# Why is the spontaneous decay rate $A_{21} \propto \omega_0^3$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, laser

I have seen the Einstein thermal equilibrium derivation that $\frac{A_{21}}{B_{21}}= \frac{\hbar \omega_0^3}{\pi^2 c^3}$, but intuitively I would expect the spontaneous decay rate $A_{21} = \frac{1}{\tau} \sim \Delta E \sim \Delta \omega$ as $\Delta E \Delta t \gt \frac{\hbar}{2}$.

In other words I would expect the spontaneous decay rate to be inversely proportional to the lifetime of the state which is related to the uncertainty of the energy of the state. So where does the cubed relationship come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of Fermi golden rule, transition rate (probability per time unit) is proportional to the matrix element of the transition and density of states in the final state. What you wrote is indeed true for the matrix element, but spontaneous decay rate is accompanied by the emission of a photon. In other words, it is not just you have to be able to have an optical transition, it's also that you have to have space where to emit this photon. So, you also have to account for the free space density of states of photons.

There are various derivations for the latter (the one usually taught involves considering a rectangular box and then extending it into infinitely large one while counting standing waves as photon modes in it), but anyway, number of photons at energy $E$ is proportional to $E^3$, so their density of states if the derivative, and thus proportional to $E^2$. Together with $E$ from the matrix element, this gives $E^3$ in the total rate.